# stop page load in codeigniter jquery + ajax bookmark function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm working on a bookmarking function (codeigniter, jquery, ajax). Below is the HTML for the form and the jQuery code.

**Here's what's happening:**

- form is submitting the data to the database
- the page is reloading
- I'm not getting the success alert
- If I use e.preventDefault() or return false, the page doesn't reload and I get the success alert, but the data that gets passed to the database is 0.

**HTML FORM**

```
<?php echo form_open('bookmarks/addBookmark'); ?>
<?php echo form_hidden('bookn', $bname); ?>
<?php echo form_hidden('booki', $this->uri->segment(4, 0)); ?>
<button class="bb_button">Bookmark</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.bb_button').click(function() { 
            $.ajax({
                url: 'bookmarks/addBookmark',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("Your bookmark has been added.");
                }                                         
            }); 
       //return false<--this is where I used it
    });
```

Comment: You're not sending any kind of data along with your ajax request..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not passing any data in.

Try

```
$('.bb_button').click(function(e) { 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'bookmarks/addBookmark',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { bookn: $("[name='bookn']").val()​, booki: $("[name='booki']").val()​ },
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Your bookmark has been added.");
        }                                         
    }); 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: YESSSSS! For future googlers, I had to add a leading slash to the URL (think that's unique to Codeigniter) and I had to put quotes around the fields and I had to remove the spaces before and after the data (e.g., {"bookn": ...). Works like a CHARM