# use jquery dialog button to submit form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Working on a submit function from a jQuery dialog (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432556/stop-page-load-in-codeigniter-jquery-ajax-bookmark-function/10432720) question). Using codeigniter and jquery.

I'd like to tie the ajax POST to the jquery dialog button click, but don't know what the selector should be for that button. I tried to use .ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first or "this" as the selector; neither worked.

**HTML FORM**

```
<?php echo form_open('bookmarks/addBookmark'); ?> //form name: create_bookmark
<?php echo form_input('bookn', $bname); ?>
<?php echo form_hidden('booki', $this->uri->segment(4, 0)); ?>
<button class="bb_button">Bookmark</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

        $( "#create_bookmark" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 250,
            height: 250,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Add location": function() {    

                $('?????').click(function() {  //How do I specify the dialog button?

            $.ajax({
                url: '/bookmarks/addBookmark',
                type: 'POST',
                data:{"bookn": $("input[name='bookn']").val()​, "booki": $("[name='booki']").val()​},
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("Your bookmark has been added.");
                }                                         
            }); 
                },
                Cancel: function() {$( this ).dialog( "close" );}
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you specify in the `buttons` object *is* the click handler.
You can send your request right in that function.

Comment: I removed the (duplicate) click function I had added and got the success dialog, but nothing went to the database. Will keep checking.

Comment: Nope, it's not working. I know the ajax code is fine, since I'm using it elsewhere in the app.

Comment: @chowwy: What do you see in Firebug?

Comment: Thanks; accepted and upvoted. I'm getting the success message now, but nothing's going to the database. Can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like after I broke it out and indented properly, you were missing a `}` This is presuming the implementation of Slaks's answer

```
        buttons: {
          "Add location": function() {    

            $.ajax({
              url: '/bookmarks/addBookmark',
              type: 'POST',
              data:{
                "bookn": $("input[name='bookn']").val()​, 
                "booki": $("[name='booki']").val()
              ​},
              success: function (result) {
                alert("Your bookmark has been added.");
              }
          });                                       
        } //<<This one
```